# How to setup Laravel 5.4 reset password from one table for multiple user type

Tags: php, laravel-5, passwords

Till now what I learnt from many tutorials an documents that to create reset password for another type of user( like seller, editor , vendor) other than the basic user I have to create different reset password form, controller for every user type.

The process will get to long if the user type is more than 4-5 and managing the code is harder.

Is there any process where one reset password form will search the respective user type  depending on the email provided and send the reset password link to the mail and link get back to the same new password form for all user.

**Thank you. 
If u have any issues to understand my question comments bellow I will explain more what I need**

Comment: Why do you have different forms for password reset ? I guess all your users are in the same table, with a `type` column

Comment: No I don't, I have dirrent user type and each user has  different fields. That's y I created different model for each user type. Tell me which is best way to solve my issue

Comment: I think it will be easier to use only one table for users, and some tables for additionnal informations according to user's type.

Comment: What you are telling I get that , you are right , which easily possible by laratrust , but I wanna use less package  for my projects that's y m asking like in config/auth.php you will find the reset_password at the end which use only users for reset password I just want to search the user fromm different models